# Advanced search with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

I have this table (tblStudent) in Sql Server:

| Id | Name | Age | PlaceOfBirthId | CityId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | N1 | 11 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | N2 | 19 | 4 | 6 |
| 3 | N3 | 11 | 3 | 56 |
| 4 | N4 | 14 | 8 | 11 |
| 5 | N5 | 13 | 27 | 12 |
| 6 | N6 | 21 | 25 | 45 |
| 7 | N7 | 33 | 9 | 7 |
| 8 | N8 | 23 | 8 | 71 |
| 9 | N9 | 15 | 76 | 71 |
| 10 | N10 | 41 | 13 | 3 |

I want to filter this table by PlaceOfBirthId and CityId. is my filter list:

| FilterId | FilterValue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 56 |
| 2 | 71 |

Filter Id **1**: is PlaceOfBirthId And Filter Id **2**: CityId. َAlso, My filter list may contain one or more filter type. I want to use "or" operator for similar type of filter and "and" operator for different types.

The list after filtering should look like this:

| Id | Name | Age | PlaceOfBirthId | CityId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | N3 | 11 | 3 | 56 |
| 8 | N8 | 23 | 8 | 71 |

(Filter Id 1: 3 Or 8) And (Filter Id 2: 56 Or 71) And...

**The filter may be on one or more columns**

Comment: If the "filter" table is so specific, why not create views or functions instead? Creating rows isn't more dynamic than creating views. You'll have to generate dynamic SQL anyway

Comment: There's no way to guess that Filter ID 1 is `PlaceOfBirthId` for example. You'll have to map that number to the `PlaceOfBirthId` and emit `PlaceOfBirthId = 3`. Why not do that once?

Comment: Not related, but you don't store `Age`. You store `DateOfBirth`, then calculate `Age` based on a point in time at extraction.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select *
from tblstudent s
where exists (
  select 1 from filter f 
  where f.filterid = 1 and f.filtervalue = s.placeofbirth
) 
  and exists (
  select 1 from filter f 
  where f.filterid = 2 and f.filtervalue = s.cityid
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I said in the question that the number of samples of my filter is not known. That's why I can't consider filters as fixed

Comment: Then, you can use Dynamic SQL to assemble the full statement as in this example. However, there's a piece of information missing in your question, if you want to make it dynamic. How will the query know the column that "filter #3" or "filter #4" will apply to?

Comment: My table is an example. Each column has its own key ID. The filter may be for one column or multiple columns

Comment: This answer addresses your actual question. If your actual tables are different, post actual tables and data. This isn't about SQL, it's about how you've stored query definitions as tables instead of as eg views, stored procedures or functions. If the criteria are so specific, they should be views, not table rows. You'll have to generate dynamic SQL one way or another.